# SQL Server variable use

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm hoping someone could help me identify why this query is causing me a syntax error?

This is part of a script that works when I hard code and define `@modifiedFileLocation` to be `C:\Program Files` --- whatever.

I have set and printed out `modifiedFileLocation` right before this step and it prints what I expect. I'm trying to use that value inside of this query here:

```
( NAME = N$(databaseName), FILENAME = 'N' + @modifiedFileLocation  + '\$(databaseName).mdf' , SIZE = 1048576KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
```

I'm getting this error message:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I'm not sure what it needs to look like, and any help/insight would be appreciated

Comment: Can you share any more of your query?

Comment: Is this part of an ALTER DATABASE call by any chance?

Comment: This is part of an ALTER DATABASE command

Comment: Looks like the whole sql statement needs to be put into a variable (if it isn't already) and used in an EXEC() or sp_executesql call (ref: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic703142-338-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I think the $(databaseName) is already a string, so it doesn't need the '. Also, the \ needs to be escaped. Hope I'm not too far off :)

```
( NAME = N$(databaseName), FILENAME = 'N' + @modifiedFileLocation  + '\\'+$(databaseName)+'.mdf' , SIZE = 1048576KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
```

Comment: Gave this a shot, still no luck, I'm getting the same error with this as well.

Comment: $(databaseName) works fine when it's treated as a string type in my original example, it's the variable that I SET in the query that is giving me issues

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you're trying to build a NVARCHAR in the statement.  Try declaring another variable and setting the value before the call.

```
DECLARE @nvarPath NVARCHAR(MAX) = @modifiedFileLocation  + '\\'+ $(databaseName) + '.mdf'

( NAME = N$(databaseName), FILENAME = @nvarPath , SIZE = 1048576KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )
```

Comment: well I can't declare that, because then it would override what I had before

Comment: not sure what that means.. but you can't do string concatenations in function calls.. just like you can't do `exec sp_executesql N'Select * From ' + 'Table1'`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what I was asking in the original question as is. Instead, I found another way to do this.

Save the whole script (whatever to stored procedure is) into a variable

```
DECLARE @sqlscriptname varchar(MAX)

@sqlscriptname = <THE WHOLE SCRIPT>
```

instead of declaring variables such as @logPath declare it like this {logPath}
example: 
     ( NAME = N{databaseName}, FILENAME = 'N''{logPath}'' , SIZE = 1048576KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10240KB )

**NOTE: You will need to use quadruple ticks ('''') in order to quote string variables you're replacing; double ticks to escape('') the string and another double ticks to add a tick**

and then use this function:

```
SET @sqlscriptname = REPLACE(@sqlscriptname, '{logPath}', @modifiedFileLocation + '$(databaseName)_log.ldf')
```

Then once the replace is done you can simply run:

```
EXECUTE(@sqlscriptname)
```

Very convoluted way of doing it, but it seems to be the best way in a store procedure